# Handling errors with iostream

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm working on `[Bjarne_Stroustrup]Programming-Principles-and-Practice-Using-C++` book from 2008, 5. chapter called `Errors` is using `std_lib_facilities.h` and function called `error`.

Here is example :

```
if(x<=0) error("non-positive x");
if(y<=0) error("non-positive y");
int area1=area(x,y);
```

Since I use *Visual Studio 2012* which don't have `std_lib_facilities.h`, this error handler is not working! What is `iostream`'s error handling function and where can I find and study it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ Standard Library's header files (`iostream`, `vector`, etc.) don't have `.h` on the end.  (Most third-party libraries, however, do use the `.h`.)  Since `std_lib_facilities.h` does have a .h, it's reasonable to assume it's not a standard library and not something that Visual C++ should be expected to provide.

In this case, a quick Google search reveals that it's provided with your book and downloadable from http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h.

Comment: What can i do with all that text?

Comment: @user3446166 - Save it as another file in your project directory so that you can #include it.

Comment: i called it std_facilities, #included it like this #include <std_facilities.cpp> and got this :fatal error C1083: "Cannot open include file: 'std_facilities.cpp': No such file or directory" ,without .cpp same thing

Comment: Call it `std_lib_facilities.h` and include it as `#include <std_lib_facilities.h>`.  Including a `.cpp` file is technically legal but is considered very bad style in C++.

Answer (score 5):

`std_lib_facilities.h` is a helper header written by Bjarne Stroustrup.

> It provides the most common standard headers (in the global namespace)
>     and minimal exception/error support.

You can find it [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/) under shortcut: **Standard library access header**.

An error function is defined as follows:

```
// error() simply disguises throws:
inline void error(const string& s)
{
    throw runtime_error(s);
}
```

---

### Visual Studio

[Here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/include-std_lib_facilities.doc) you can find a tutorial on how to get `std_lib_facilities.h` working on VS.

---

There is also note for a students...

> Students: please don't try to understand the details of headers just
>   yet.  All will be explained. This header is primarily used so that you
>   don't have    to understand every concept all at once.

Answer (score 0):

> Since im using Visual Studio 2012 which dont have
>   "std_lib_facilities.h", this error handler is not working! What is
>   iostream's error handling function and where can i find and study it?

std_lib_facilities.h header is not something which c++ standard  has provided. Hence you are getting such error in VS2012. You need to write your own logic and put it into the some file and include it into your program.

You may implement your own basic version of error() function as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
template<typename T>
void error(const T& msg) {
 std::cerr<<msg<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @user93353: Yes I know about this and in general we throw exception. But in my response I have mentioned about own basic version of error() function.